# Div height doesn't always return the same number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $('#home_sidebar').height();
});
```

to get the height of my home_sidebar div. The code is only executed when the page is fully loaded. However it returns different numbers from time to time. For example, sometimes it says 1699, sometimes it returns 1398.

There are "img" and "a" tags inside this div, what could possibly go wrong?

By the way, I am implementing a docking div on http://www.city365.ca. If you see the colored icons stick to the top of the page, it is working.

If you see the colored icons docking at the bottom of the page, it is not working.

Comment: The images haven't finished fully loading before you are accessing this height.

Comment: Most likely the images haven't finished loading yet. Use the `$(window).load()` method and try with that.

Comment: Maybe you load the page with an opened console? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(window).load()` to make sure your images are loaded

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var height = $('#home_sidebar').height();
});
```

Comment: Read the `Caveats of the load event when used with images` http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ as this method is not reliable either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var height = $('#home_sidebar').height();
});
```

`$(window).on('load'...` will wait for the images to load before firing.

Answer (score 0):

I would also state another (obvious) possibility which is that you resized the window between loads. Just to be complete :)